# What level of a Plug and Play Manager works?

Tags: windows, operating-system, driver, hardware

When a new device pluged in to, let's say, a USB hub. What is the magic work behind the scene between

- `a device is pluged in`
- `the user of the computer can use the device`

After several days of digging. There is still some confusions that I can't worked out on my own.

Currently my understanding of this processing is that ( in windows system ):

- A device pluged in
- Windows look up in its registry to find a appropriate driver for it
- call the `DriverEntry` routine of the driver
- call the `AddDevice` routine of the driver

What role of a `Plug and Play Manager` is playing ? It seems like this processing can work fine even without one.

Comment: Does this help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/pnp-manager ?

Comment: In fact, I just came back from there...

Comment: It is the xHCI controller of the USB hub which triggers an interrupt when a new USB device has been attached to a computer.